# Run a jar file from unix command line

Tags: java

I have created a jar file from mvn command but when i am trying to run it i am getting below error :

```
java -cp target/new-repl.jar package.repl
Error: Could not find or load main class package.repl
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package.repl
```

I got many links on stack overflow but none of them helped me. Could you please help me to run this from command line. Below is the my .java file:

```
package repl;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ....
    }
}
```

POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>repl</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>repl</name>
        <description>build tar for repl</description>
      
  <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <finalName>new-repl</finalName>
    <directory>target</directory>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What is the class name you're trying to run (hint - it does *not* start with `package`)

Comment: @stdunbar class name is Test

Comment: But the "full path" of the the class is `repl.Test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this. Type fully qualified class name instead of typing package name

```
java -cp target/new-repl.jar repl.Test
```

The error says it all

```
Error: Could not find or load main class package.repl
```

your class name is not package.repl, it is `repl.Test`